Cypher Queries in NEO4J Community Edition: Not able to create the Roles,Attach the Roles to Users,Add the Database Permissions(i.e. read) to the Roles
I am using the NEO4J community edition but am having issues with some cypher queries

I am not able to grant the roles because the GRANT command is not
working.
I am not able to create the roles in the NEO4J community edition using the command CREATE ROLE reader.
I am not able to add the DataBase Permissions to the Users.

More Details about the issues I am facing:

I am not able to grant the roles because the GRANT command is not working.
The error message is below:

Neo.ClientError.Statement.UnsupportedAdministrationCommand
Unsupported administration command: GRANT ROLE reader TO xyz


I am not able to create the roles in the NEO4J community edition using the command CREATE ROLE reader.

The error message is as follows:
Neo.ClientError.Statement.UnsupportedAdministrationCommand
Unsupported administration command: CREATE ROLE reader


I am trying to add the adminstrator permission to all the neo4j databases to the role (for ex:- admin) using the command GRANT ACCESS ON DATABASE * TO admin but I don't think this will be executed as well since we are able to create the roles as shown in point number 2.

The above cypher queries are working for the NEO4J Enterprise Edition but are not executable in the NEO4J Community Edition
Can you please suggest me to resolve the above 3 issues I am facing?

As documented:

In Neo4j Community Edition there are no roles, but all users have
implied administrator privileges.

So, creating roles and granting permissions to roles is only supported in the Enterprise Edition.
